# Linq-to-SQL gridview add sum column

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview

I have this linq query in GridView

```
 var table = from ll in dbo.Workers
                    join p in dbo.WorkDays on ll.Id equals p.Id
                    orderby p.Enter
                    select new
                    {
                        ll.Id,
                        ll.Name,
                        ll.Salary,
                        p.Enter,
                        p.ExitT,
                        p.Place,
                        WorkTime = Math.Round(getWorkTime(p.Enter, p.ExitT), 2),
                        Earned = Math.Round(getEarned(p.Enter, p.ExitT, ll.Salary), 2),
                    };
```

How can I add column of sum to the table?

Comment: What sum do you want to add?

Comment: Thats what I thought about - see solution below

Answer (score 1):

Create class which will hold data and provide calculations based on that data:

```
public class WorkerInfo
{
    // I don't know exact type of fields, but its enough for you to get the idea
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public DateTime Enter { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExitT { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }

    public int WorkTime
    {
       get { return (ExitT - Enter).TotalDays; }
    }

    public decimal Earned
    {
       get { return WorkTime * Salary; }
    }
}
```

Fill that these entities with data:

```
var workers = from ll in dbo.Workers
              join p in dbo.WorkDays on ll.Id equals p.Id
              orderby p.Enter
              select new WorkerInfo
              {
                 Id = ll.Id,
                 Name = ll.Name,
                 Salary = ll.Salary,
                 Enter = p.Enter,
                 ExitT = p.ExitT,
                 Place = p.Place
              };
```

---

*UPDATE* Sample for returning aggregated data for all days:

```
var query = from w in dbo.Workers
            join d in dbo.WorkDays on w.Id equals d.Id into days
            let WorkTime = days.Sum(d => d.ExitT - d.Enter)
            select new 
              {
                 w.Id,
                 w.Name,
                 w.Salary,
                 WorkTime,
                 Earned = WorkTime * w.Salary
              };
```

Comment: as long as the entity class Worker is not already part of the dbo context right?

Comment: @JorgeAlvarado exactly! I'll rename it to be sure

Comment: @ariel which table? Your method returned collection of anonymous objects. Now these objects have type WorkerInfo

Comment: I think It was a nomenclature issue, probably he just means projection or the grid that he sees in the form, just a guess though.

Comment: your solution is to find WorkTime and Earned for each day,
but i need to find sum for all days
sorry if i not clearly

Comment: How you gonna do summary for several days, if you return Enter and Exit of each day? Also you are joining tables by id. Are you sure your FK in WorkDays have name id?

Comment: It's very unclear what are you trying to achieve and what type of data you have, but I provided you sample which shows an idea of calculating totals for all days

Comment: @lazyberezovsky sorry, I messed up the whole thing, I'll better delete my post and let yo answer it, thanks :)

Comment: @JorgeAlvarado don't be hurry! I'm still not sure any of us understands what OP really asking :)